# Protractor - 3.1.1 - sendkeys failing with error message ENAMETOOLONG: name too long,

Tags: angularjs, protractor, sendkeys

I have recently migrated E2E tests to start using Protractor 3.1.1 from 2.6.1. I have started seeing following failures when sending random Text with length over 300 chars using SendKeys method. The tests are passing when restricting random text length to 255 chars.

Before migration these tests were working fine. Would you pleas advise if some one had come across this issue and how to resolve this without work-around like restricting string length.

```
Error Message:
 Message:
    Failed: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, stat 'incidunt magni recusandae earum voluptatem ipsam voluptatem ea fugit a
    minus est fuga et labore facere est voluptas ullam est
    corporis nihil itaque similique est accusamus ut perspiciatis molestiae
    tempora et sunt sint architecto qui
    maxime laboriosam alias eveniet assumenda id
    eius cumque et assumenda dolorum blanditiis dolorem perferendis eos eum'
  Stack:
    Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, stat 'incidunt magni recusandae earum voluptatem ipsam voluptatem ea fugit a
    minus est fuga et labore facere est voluptas ullam est
    corporis nihil itaque similique est accusamus ut perspiciatis molestiae
    tempora et sunt sint architecto qui
    maxime laboriosam alias eveniet assumenda id
    eius cumque et assumenda dolorum blanditiis dolorem perferendis eos eum'
        at Error (native)
    From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
        at Array.map (native)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:9)
    Error
        at /protractor-e2e/page-objects/util.js:83:21
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:9)
    From: Task: Run it("sample test") in control flow
```

Comment: Do you see this behavior in all the different browsers?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm running into this problem when I run my tests inside a Ubuntu docker image. Works fine running on Windows. Only throws this error when I run the tests in the Linux container.